# По какой-то причине в Android Studio курсор становится черным

Tags: android-studio

Редактирую тексты и вдруг курсор в Android Studio становится черным. Работать с ним неудобно и стирает он по-другому, как это исправить?
[image: пример проблемы]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Была нажата кнопка `Insert`, нажмите ещё раз чтобы выключить.